# Appending Route parameter to href

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am a beginner with ASP.NET and i am trying to append a parameter to an href link.

I am not really sure how to get the href to look like `https://www.itelde.com/flick?id=113`

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.itelde.com/flick?id=" asp-route-id="@Model" target="_blank">
    Flicker
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Flicker([BindRequired, FromQuery] string id)
{
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `href` itself directly, then you can just concat the things here:

```
<a href="https://www.itelde.com/flick?id=@Model" target="_blank">Flicker</a>
```

The `asp-route-id` tag helper can be used when you are generating the `href` by using `asp-page` or `asp-action` to refer to a Razor page or a controller action within your application. For example, if that `Flicker` action is part of your app, you could write it like this:

```
<a asp-action="Flicker" asp-route-id="@Model" target="_blank">Flicker</a>
```

---

If you try to use `asp-route-something` with an explicit `href`, you should also get the following error at runtime:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for <a>. An <a> with a specified 'href' must not have attributes starting with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-area', 'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host', 'asp-fragment', 'asp-page' or 'asp-page-handler' attribute.